# How format special character in formData in nodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, encoding, multipartform-data

I have a problem with encoding on special characters, let me show my code :

I have a node which post request directly on website, so i use FormData object to build form data.

The request did by a browser (got the CURL) :
In all example, it's a sample of my data where i have the problem.

```
  $'-----------------------------1755811723502268269588155\r\n
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="pageId"\r\n\r\n212403390500\r\n-----------------------------1755811723502268269588155\r\n
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="CL_TEXT_CLOT"\r\n\r\nLa t\xe2che \xe9tait bloqu\xe9\r\n-----------------------------1755811723502268269588155\r\n
```

the code is :

```
const form = new FormData();
  form.append('pageId', pageId),
  form.append('pageId', pageId),
  form.append('CL_TEXT_CLOT',el.CL_TEXT_CLOT)
...

let configPost = {
method: 'POST',
headers : {'Accept': "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,/*;q=0.8",
'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary='+form._boundary,
'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.9 Safari/537.36'},
url: 'http://localhost:7000/test',
data : form,
validateStatus: function (status) {
  return status >= 200 && status < 300 || status == 302; // default
}
```

When i sent :

```
'----------------------------397600554882409697883429\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="CL_TEXT_CLOT"\r\ntype: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\n',
 'La tâche était bloqué.',
```

If i use escapeUnicode function :

```
let escapeUnicode = function (str) {
  return str.replace(/[^\0-~]/g, function(ch) {
      let tmp = "\\u" + ("000" + ch.charCodeAt().toString(16)).slice(-4);
      return tmp.replace('\\u00','\\x')
  });
}
```

in the formData, same code but with this line :

```
form.append('CL_TEXT_CLOT', escapeUnicode(el.CL_TEXT_CLOT))
```

and the result is :

```
   '----------------------------882802935214785196311782\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="CL_TEXT_CLOT"\r\ntype: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\n',
     'La t\\xe2che \\xe9tait bloqu\\xe9.',
```

formData encapsulate the \xe2 by \ so result is \xe2....

and the final code is this (with or without the escapeUnicode) :

```
 const form = new FormData();
 form.append('CL_TEXT_CLOT', escapeUnicode(el.CL_TEXT_CLOT),{ header: { type:  'text/plain; charset=UTF-8' } })
```

Do you have an idea ?
Maybe i am in the wrong way....

EDIT: I have the same program in Python, and i had this in data :

So how should i do to have special character escaped in the formData in nodeJS ???

Comment: Why do you even call `escapeUnicode` at all if `FormData` apparently does the escaping for you?

Comment: Without escape, it doesn't escaping as you can see...

Comment: But it also says `charset=UTF-8`, which means it doesn't need escaping… Just because `curl` does do some escaping doesn't mean it's necessary. Does your nodejs server actually have a problem decoding utf-8? Can you show us how you are doing that, and what the error is?

Comment: I changed, but another problem now. You need all the code ?

Comment: Only the parts of the code that accept the request and are responsible for decoding the multipart/formdata, until the point where you have the encoding problem. We need to make sure the encoding problem is not caused by your output routine or something. Also please [edit] your question to include more info instead of posting an answer without a solution.

Comment: I edited the post with complete code, formData and post request.

Comment: I did ask for the *serverside* code that is necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Don't have the server code , it's a outside service. I changed by localhost. Can say two things, i can  check the result sent on the website and i have a POC in python which worked.

Comment: Then why is this tagged [[tag:node.js]]?

Comment: I made a nodeJS server which make POST request on another public web server . Just for that...

Comment: nobody have idea ? I found nothing, how escape character correctly in a format like in python.

Answer (score 0):

I changed by :

```
     form.append('CL_TEXT_CLOT',el.CL_TEXT_CLOT)
```

It send that  :

```
   [Function: bound ],
 '----------------------------075700443350966081023154\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="CL_TEXT_CLOT"\r\n\r\n',
 'C\'est corrigé.  ',
```

I have this :

```
  C'est corrigÃ©.
```

Answer (score 0):

the following code can work:

```
     let form = new FormData()
     form.append(
        "prop",
        "some utf strings：你好",
        {
          contentType: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"
        }
     );
```